# LEFT JOIN query doesn't return expected result

Tags: mysql, sql

something is wrong with my join query or I need GROUP

```
table questions
-------------------------------------------
|     id    | questions_id1|   category  |
-------------------------------------------
|     1     |      p1      |      1       |
|     2     |      p2      |      2,1     |
|     3     |      p3      |      1       |
|     4     |      p4      |      2,1     |
|     5     |      p5      |      2,1     |
------------------------------------------
```

```
table answers
-----------------------------------------
|     id    | questions_id2 |  user_id  |
-----------------------------------------
|     1     |       p1      |    u1     |
|     2     |       p1      |    u2     |
|     3     |       p2      |    u1     |
|     4     |       p2      |    u2     |
|     5     |       p3      |    u1     |
|     6     |       p4      |    u2     |
-----------------------------------------
```

```
table extra_category
---------------------------------------------
|     id    | questions_id3 |extra_category |
---------------------------------------------
|     1     |      p1       |       1       |
|     2     |      p2       |       1       |
|     3     |      p3       |       1       |
|     4     |      p4       |       1       |
|     5     |      p5       |       1       |
---------------------------------------------
```

```
SELECT questions.*, answers.*, extra_category.* FROM extra_category
LEFT JOIN questions ON extra_category.questions_id3 = questions.questions_id1
LEFT JOIN answers ON extra_category.questions_id3 = answers.questions_id2
WHERE extra_category = 1 AND category LIKE '%1%' 
order by case when user_id = '1' then 1 else 0 end, a.id ASC
```

expected result: for user_id = 1

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     id    | question_id1 |   question_id2    | user_id  | category  | extra_category |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     4     |      p4     |     p4             |    u2    |     1     |       1        |
|     5     |      p5     |     p5             |   null   |     1     |       1        |
|     1     |      p1     |     p1             |    u1    |     1     |       1        |
|     2     |      p2     |     p2             |    u1    |     1     |       1        |
|     3     |      p3     |     p3             |    u1    |     1     |       1        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

expected result: for user_id = 2

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     id    |question_id1| question_id2|    user_id   | category   | extra_category |
-------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------|
|     3     |      p3    |      p3     |        u1    |      1     |       1        |
|     5     |      p5    |      p5     |       null   |      1     |       1        |
|     1     |      p1    |      p1     |        u2    |      1     |       1        |
|     2     |      p2    |      p2     |        u2    |      1     |       1        |
|     4     |      p4    |      p4     |        u2    |      1     |       1        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

result now for user_1 = 1

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     id    |question_id1| question_id2|   user_id | category    | extra_category |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1     |    p1      |      p1     |     u2    |       1     |       1        |
|     2     |    p2      |      p2     |     u2    |       1     |       1        |
|     4     |    p4      |      p4     |     u2    |       1     |       1        |
|     5     |    p5      |      p5     |    null   |       1     |       1        |
|     1     |    p1      |      p1     |     u1    |       1     |       1        |
|     2     |    p2      |      p2     |     u1    |       1     |       1        |
|     3     |    p3      |      p3     |     u1    |       1     |       1        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The quiz has 100 questions. Each user receives the same questions. The answers are saved in the table b. At the next time: he try to solve a test, the answers that's he already answered correctly are displayed at end. Still 100 questions.

Comment: What is `WHERE= ? OR GROUP = ?` supposed to mean? That's not valid syntax.

Comment: Your query cannot produce your expected result. Please attach your full query without ?.

And what is b_two? also, what is b_u = 1?

Comment: Please replace the placeholder arguments with valid arguments. This would also be a *LOT* easier to parse if you gave the tables/columns real names instead of a,b,c.

Comment: If c-to-a and c-to-b are both one-to-many relationships, *any* join will have results that have the cartesian products of each c's (a X b); a LEFT JOIN won't magically make that go away.

Comment: `case when b_two = '1'` There's no `b_two` column in any of the tables. Did you mean `c_two`?

Comment: I have updated questions field

Comment: Why are you expecting those results for the different user id values? The `CASE` in your `ORDER BY` clause does not perform any filtering; nothing in an `ORDER BY` can do any filtering, it is purely for sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT questions.*, answers.*, extra_category.* FROM extra_category
LEFT JOIN questions ON extra_category.questions_id3 = questions.questions_id1
LEFT JOIN answers ON extra_category.questions_id3 = answers.questions_id2 and answers.user_id = 1
WHERE extra_category = 1 AND category LIKE '%1%' 
order by case when user_id = '1' then 1 else 0 end, a.id ASC
```

works fine